# How to return all objects related to current user?

Tags: c#, mysql

Pretty new to ASP.Net and databases.  I'm trying to write a query in my EFRepository that gives me all the objects related to a user.  I've got a relationship between my cars table and users table on the UserId.  I can't get my sql query to work properly.  Any assistance is greatly appreciated!  I'd prefer lambda syntax but I can't get the join syntax right there either.  Also, is this going to return the objects related to the current user?  Thanks!

```
 public IList<Cars> GetUserCars(string userId) {
        return from c in _db.Cars.AsQueryable()
                   join u in _db.Users.AsQueryable() on c.UserId equals u.Id
               select c


    }
```

Comment: Why do you need the join to `Users` at all when the method receives a `userId`? Can't you just use `return from c in _db.Cars where c.UserId == userId select c`?

Comment: thanks.  i think that's very well on the right track, but didn't pull back the data that I hoped.  I instead got all.